# Understanding why drop.duplicates() Is not working

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a 2-row pandas dataframe that I acquired by subsetting a larger dataframe.

```
             TransID     rev    offer         qs   lt         chan  
212    RTSO118981094  737.24  ABCXCS           3  d382        O78   
53311  RTSO118981094  737.24  ABCXCS           3  d382        O78
```

The rev is a float that has been rounded to 2 decimal places.

The 2 rows look identical and when I do a "diff" there is no output.  Even so,

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

has no effect.  Their fields are all the same length.

How to get this to work?

Comment: Eagle-Eye MaxU.  :)

Comment: Why the downvotes on the question though. A well-formulated problem with data and a clear question.

Comment: sorry my orig q had a typo. all fields are same.

Comment: @MarkGinsburg In that case use `df.to_dict()` and post it here.

Comment: You probably have whitespace in one of the columns.  As @AntonvBR points out, using to_dict() will help with this issue.

Comment: If you answer 'to_dict' I will accept that answer.  It revealed the problem right away which was qs was a string in row1 and a "L" in row2.

Comment: @MarkGinsburg Sure, but I would advice you to use dtypes in the future as it can help you figure out errors

Comment: I also can't understand that many downvotes...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well in this case the problem was the mixed types you had. A common way to investigate your data is to export it with, e.g. `to_dict()`

```
df.to_dict()
```

Also consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [3,3],
    'b': ["d382","d382"]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['3',3],
    'b': ["d382","d382"]
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['3','3'],
    'b': ["d382","d382"]
})

print(df1.dtypes) # <-- Use dtypes to reveal what data types your columns hold
print(df2.dtypes) # <-- Use dtypes to reveal what data types your columns hold
print(df3.dtypes) # <-- Use dtypes to reveal what data types your columns hold
```

Returns:

```
df1               df2               df3
a     int64       a    object       a    object
b    object       b    object       b    object
dtype: object     dtype: object     dtype: object
```

---

**Further exploring:** In pandas the object type can hold different types. That can create a tricky situation where we mix integers, lists, classes... you name it.

Let us now select only those columns and use `applymap(type)` to find out the type in each cell. Looking at the above examples the erraneous dataframe is df2 which in column `a` hold different types of object.

```
print(df1.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(type))
print(df2.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(type))
print(df3.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(type))

               b
0  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>
               a              b
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>       # <--- look at column a
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>       # <--- it has mixed types
               a              b
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>
```

And finally, let us now create a function that goes through all object columns and check if everything is correct. This is defined by the length of the set of values in each column. In a *"correct"* column all elements should be of same type:

```
def check_obj_columns(dfx):
    tdf = dfx.select_dtypes(include=['object']).applymap(type)
    for col in tdf:
        if len(set(tdf[col].values)) > 1:
            print("Column {} has mixed object types.".format(col))

check_obj_columns(df1) # Returns nothing
check_obj_columns(df2) # Returns: Column a has mixed object types.
check_obj_columns(df3) # Returns nothing
```

This means that the df2 has a object column `a` with mixed types.

---

In your case:

```
TransID     object
rev        float64
offer       object
qs          object   # <-- this element here is an object if you got mixed types
lt          object
chan        object
dtype: object
```

Comment: I had only investigated the length of each column and did not anticipate the mixed type that to_dict() revealed.

Comment: @AntonvBR Great example!  +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Thanks.. what do you think about my further exploring part. Does it make sense?

Comment: @MarkGinsburg I created a function called `check_obj_columns`. Do you mind testing it with your dataframe?

Comment: sure, i'll test it