# Mixed object type columns and managing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, merge, duplicates

I have merged 4 datasets and I can note duplicated rows in the data frame. However, when I command pandas to show me the duplicated rows, it says there is none and hence my codes to remove duplicated rows is not responding. Any help would be appreciated.

Dataframe sample:

```
end_time_x  start_time_x    duration    deviceuuid  time_offset_x   exercise_type   max_speed   calorie mean_speed  distance    ... time_offset create_time weekday month   startsleep  wakeup  sleep_duration  duration_mins   powernaps   weekend
0   2018-01-07 10:01:00-04:00   2018-01-07 07:21:00-04:00   831210  F/D7+hL5E5  UTC-0300    1001    1.750000    54.340  1.376099    905.360 ... UTC-0400    2018-01-07 10:15:59.770000-04:00    6   1   7   10  02:40:00    160.0   False   True
1   2018-01-07 10:01:00-04:00   2018-01-07 07:21:00-04:00   831210  F/D7+hL5E5  UTC-0300    1001    1.750000    54.340  1.376099    905.360 ... UTC-0400    2018-01-07 05:12:34.278000-04:00    6   1   0   4   04:12:00    252.0   False   True
2   2018-01-07 10:01:00-04:00   2018-01-07 07:21:00-04:00   831210  F/D7+hL5E5  UTC-0300    1001    1.750000    54.340  1.376099    905.360 ... UTC-0400    2018-01-08 07:45:13.936000-04:00    6   1   22  7   09:11:00    551.0   False   True
3   2018-01-07 10:01:00-04:00   2018-01-07 07:21:00-04:00   831210  F/D7+hL5E5  UTC-0300    1001    1.750000    54.340  1.376099    905.360 ... UTC-0400    2018-01-07 10:15:59.770000-04:00    6   1   7   10  02:40:00    160.0   False   True
```

I have tried the code below yet they yield the same result if I omit the drop_duplicates lines.

code for checking duplicates:

```
df_merged.duplicated().sum()
df_merged.loc[df_merged.duplicated(),:]
```

code for merging data frames by first dropping duplicates in 2 out of 4 data frames:

```
df_exercise_cleaned=df_exercise.drop_duplicates()
df_HR_cleaned=df_HR.drop_duplicates()    df_merged=df_exercise_cleaned.merge(df_HR_cleaned,on='date',how='inner').merge(df_FC, on='date',how='inner').merge(df_sleep,on='date',how='inner')
```

adding the dtypes post checking for mixed object columns and converting date to dt:
[image: df dtypes]

Comment: check the datatypes, if there is a mismatch , this could happen : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686970/understanding-why-drop-duplicates-is-not-working

Comment: Thank you - yes, my 'date' column has mixed object types. All comments and questions appear to ask for a way to check for the error; how can we get the resolution to address it?

Comment: can you assign a `datetime` to all components by `df[['time1','time2','time3']] = df[['time1','time2','time3']].apply(pd.to_datetime,errors='coerce')` and then dedup? replace time1,2 and 3 with original column names

Comment: I applied datetime to the date column with mixed object types (without errors 'coerce' ) but it still props up as a mixed object type column: df_merged['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_merged['date'])

Comment: Can't seem to move this to chat but wouldn't that impact my int and float columns that are needed for analysis and visualization?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185989/discussion-between-sfsn-and-anky-91).